# Paperclip Post request not uploading image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am trying to upload image via post request in paperclip.

I got success in executing request but request is not uploading image.

My Picture model

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :images, :images_file_name
   has_attached_file :images  
   do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :images                                  
end
```

My Controller

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController     
  def event_desc_image
    @image_url = Picture.create!(images: params[:images])             
    render :json => @image_url      
  end      
end
```

In rails console its firing following command

```
[paperclip] saving /pictures/images/000/000/004/original/tcs.png
[AWS S3 200 3.948386 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"clot1",:content_length=>88200,:content_type=>"image/png",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: tcs.png,:key=>"pictures/images/000/000/004/original/tcs.png")  

[paperclip] saving /pictures/images/000/000/004/medium/tcs.png
[AWS S3 200 0.878744 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"clot1",:content_length=>24067,:content_type=>"image/png",:data=>Paperclip::FileAdapter: f3dfe432021081dc257184b8a895464420160401-4627-1usx855,:key=>"pictures/images/000/000/004/medium/tcs.png")  

[paperclip] saving /pictures/images/000/000/004/thumb/tcs.png
[AWS S3 200 0.560126 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"clot1",:content_length=>4416,:content_type=>"image/png",:data=>Paperclip::FileAdapter: f3dfe432021081dc257184b8a895464420160401-4627-ui906j,:key=>"pictures/images/000/000/004/thumb/tcs.png")
```

But its not saving any image data. 
Object looks like:

```
+----+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| id | image_file_name | image_content_type | image_file_size | image_updated_at | created_at              | updated_at              | caption |
+----+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| 1  |                 |                    |                 |                  | 2016-04-01 17:55:05 UTC | 2016-04-01 17:55:05 UTC |         |
-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
```

Please suggest solution.
Thanks

Comment: Did you permit the :images in params in the controller?

Comment: I am using attr_accessor

Answer (score 1):

Add :image into the permitted parameter list in the picture controller.

Comment: I am not able to do that because I am getting param in following format
parameter: Parameters: {"images"=>#<ActionDi.... } 
So I cant write 
params.require(:picture).permit(:images)

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController 

  def event_desc_image
    @image = Picture.create!(photo_params)             
    render :json => @image      
  end

  private

  def photo_params
    params.permit(:image)
  end

end
```

Thanks @Brian

Comment: I've the same problem when I upload the image from my ios app,
can you please provide your multipart request.
My case is : (Model) has_attached_file :avatar_default and On ios app NSObject with attributs avatar_default_file_name | avatar_default_content | avatar_default_content_type

Answer (score -1):

What do you see with:

```
 return render json: params
```

as event_desc_image first line?